# Polymer not changing value of defined property

Tags: javascript, polymer, twitter-digits

I am using digits-api for login. I am initializing the script on attach using attached life cycle event.

```
attached: function(){
         console.log("Attached")
         Digits.init({ consumerKey: '************' });
        }
```

Then On clicking the Button it user can login.

```
onLoginButtonTap : function(){
        Digits.logIn().done(this.onLogIn).fail(this.onFail);
        },
```

When the user successfully login it will go to onLogIn function.

```
onLogIn: function() {
            console.log("Login Successfull");
            this.loginStatus="Log Out"
        }
```

So what I am doing is changing text inside paper button from Log In to Log out.
I have a property login status.

```
loginStatus:{
      type : String,
      value: "Log In",
      notify: true,
      reflectToAttribute: true
      }
```

When I try to change text in onLogIn method using this.loginStatus="Log Out". **It  says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'loginStatus' of undefined.** So basically I saw this in my other codes too. I am not able to access ids of elements inside function inside a function. Same is the matter here **I am not able to change value of property in function inside a function.** How do I recover from this problem.

```
<paper-button raised class="custom indigo" id="logIn">[[loginStatus]]</paper-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that `this` is `undefined`. In your case, you should [bind `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) when specifying the callback:

```
Digits.logIn().done(this.onLogIn.bind(this)).fail(this.onFail.bind(this));
```

Comment: One more question what should I do when I have three levels of functions. When I do this it works upto 2 levels of functions. For example if I have another function inside onLogIn function. Then it is not able to access variables again.